# Avoid validating WSDL every time the web service is executed

Tags: jboss, wsdl, xsd, xerces, xml-validation

I have a small app running in JBoss that uses web services and every time they are called, it parses the WSDL and tries to fetch from xmlsoap.org [1] in order to validate it (the WSDL).

Is there a way to avoid this validations? The problem is that:

1. It's slowing down the system and
2. Many times xmlsoap.org [1] doesn't return correctly (returns broken HTML instead of XML).

I could make schemas.xmlsoap.org point to localhost and serve the schema from there, but it seems like a very dirty solution. There must be a way to run JBoss/xerces in non-validating mode or something.

[1] http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/

Answer (score 1):

It [does look like](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html) there's a way to run xerces in non-validating mode.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use a resolver to cleanly deliver the schema from classpath.

2) Turn off validation. It's pretty unlikely that JBoss lacks a way to configure that.